# UISlider accessibility traits for VoiceOver?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, accessibility, uislider

What are are the proper UIAccessibility traits and handlers required to make a UISlider usable with VoiceOver enabled?

Are there any descriptions of how a user might use a UISlider with VoiceOver enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up adding to a UISlider for VoiceOver accessibility:

```
[ mySlider setIsAccessibilityElement:YES ];
[ mySlider setAccessibilityLabel:@"This slider controls blah blah etc...." ];
```

And in the target method for the control event UIControlEventValueChanged:

```
[ mySlider setAccessibilityValue = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah blah is set to %3.1f", mySlider.value];
```

With VoiceOver enabled, this slider then spoke the new value as I swiped up and down (not back and forth) over it after setting the focus to that slider.

Comment: Hi hotpaw2... i got a problem something similar to u.... i have posted my question  in this page... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059108/unable-to-implement-uislider-for-accessibility-option-in-ipad. Can you please help me to implement this pleaseeee.....