# Unable to implement UISlider for Accessibility option in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, accessibility, uislider, voiceover

i am trying to implement accessibility option in my book reader app. I have a slider(similar to ibooks) which is used for navigating between pages. i have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915540/uislider-accessibility-traits-for-voiceover) posted by another user and implemented the same code in my app. Right now my slider is responding when i'm tapping on it. The voiceover is also speaking the label i have given in the code. But, the problem is that, i am unable to change the slider value and navigate to another page.. I dont know if it is the problem with my code or is it that i do not know how to replicate the gesture to change the value of the slider... Any help in this regard will be appreciated.... Thanku

Answer (score 0):

Does the slider work with VoiceOver turned off?

If so, try swiping vertically up or down (top to bottom of display) after selecting the slider element with VoiceOver enabled.

Comment: hi hotpaw... Thanks for the answer... To my surprise, the slider worked just once... my slider is working when voiceover is turned off. IT is working even when the voice over is turned on. i have checked it in simulator through accessibility inspector and also on the device. When i move my finger up and down the screen, i am getting a kind of "tic-tic-tic" sound which is indicating that the slider is responding... But, when i try to move the slider(or change the value of it), the slider is not moving.. I think its my inability to move the slider in the correct direction...

Answer (score 0):

Is it a UISlider, or something of your own devising? UISlider needs an actual vertical swipe once selected, and moves a pretty significant amount as a result — not a good experience for going to the next page.

If it's your own custom control, be sure you set UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable.

Comment: I was shocked that one of my sliders seemed to accept only swipes up, not down. It has a fairly small range, like 1..3.